# Android 7.0 Settings> Display size set to small impact on current implementation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support, android-tablet-layout

My current implementation to support multiple devices when specific layouts are needed for mobile, tablets (7' and 10') was to have separate layouts in layout normal, large , xlarge folders respectively.

However, from Android 7.0, user can change the display size. When display size is set to small, its causing it fall under large category and it start to pick large folder resources.

To solve this problem, i am planning to rename large and x large to 600dp and 720dp. As large and xlarge were intended to support 7' and 10' tablets.

Is this approach correct, will layout-normal, layout-sw600dp, layout-sw720dp will cover mobiles , 7' and 10' tablets ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our conclusion is working on the basis of smallest width attribute gives the correct behaviour - layout-sw600dp, layout-sw720dp

Read more about smallest width - 
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Thanks.